# perl multiple regex with found patterns index

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script that searches for different substrings(totally unrelated substrings) in another array of strings. I have for now implemented it using loop and 'if-else if-else if' tests. I search for individual substring in the array of strings and break on the first match. I wish to know whether it is possible to optimize it further by avoiding the loops ? Is it possible, like search all the substrings in a single statement and get the index of substring which is available in the string.

E.g. let the array of substrings be name substring (type @) and have elements (abc,c10,9GH). And there is another array strings named, for instance 'buffers' (type @). Depending upon which substring matches I have to invoke some specific function. Currently, my pseudo code is:

```
Loop through the buffers:
check:
if found abc -> call funABC()
else if found c10 -> call funC10()
else if found 9GH -> call fun9GH()
```

I totally want to avoid the second if-else if-else if statements and optimize it further. Does Perl have any support for this ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're asking. Can you post your current code, and some example input and output?

Comment: Questions end with the character `'?'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %actions = (
    abc   => sub { do something },
    c10   => sub { do something },
    '9GH' => sub { do something }
);

my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %action;
$re = qr/($re)/;

for my $buffer (@buffers) {
  $action{$1}->() if $buffer =~ m/$re/;
}
```

Good news, the search is linear up to ten thousand of substrings because it is translated into trie (Aho-Corasick).

Comment: Thanks Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil. This is what I wanted to do except for the function call part. I want to call different functions for different substring match. If the buffer matched 'abc' then it should call funcabc(), if c10 matched it should call funcc10() and so on. So I want to the the first key which matched.

Comment: @tecMav So write `funabc()` in place of `do something`.

Comment: @tecMav Or use `&{"fun$1"} if $buffer =~ m/$re/;` which I would not recommend. It is far less flexible from mine point of view. It is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of not understanding your question correctly...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# hardcode some strings and substrings
my @strs = ("abc,c10,9GH",
            "abc,c10",
            "c10,9GH",
            "abc,9GH",
            "abc",
            "c10",
            "9GH");
my @substrs = ("abc",
               "c10",
               "9GH");

# store booleans in an array for each string
my @matches = (); 
for (my $i = 0; $i < @strs; $i++) {
    my @match = (); 
    for (my $j = 0; $j < @substrs; $j++) {
        if ($strs[$i] =~ m/$substrs[$j]/) {
            push @match => 1;
        } else {
            push @match => 0;
        }   
    }   
    push @matches => @match;
```

Now you can iterate through `@matches`, which stores an array indicating what substrings matched for each buffer.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This is what my code is doing currently. The question is, is there a way to avoid the loops?